# Rangy expands for cyrillic

Tags: selection, rangy

I'm using [Rangy plugin](http://rangy.googlecode.com) and textRange module and there is a problem. Then I'm using selection.expand('word') on the such text "расстояние {москва} геленджика" (selected text in brackets) Rangy expands it to the adjacent words and I got such selected texts "{расстояние москва геленджика}". But in this case I already have a selected word! I just need expanding to {москва} in м{оск}ва situations.

How can I solve this? What is the difference between different languages, that causing this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [answered this on the Rangy forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rangy/vaRYk0qugSs). In case that link stops working, here's what I wrote:

---

It's set up for Latin script by default, but you can specify a regular expression in the `expand()` method. The default is `/[a-z0-9]+('[a-z0-9]+)*/gi`, which is pretty basic but provided as a reasonable default for English.

A simple example:

```
sel.expand("word", {
    wordOptions: {
        wordRegex: /[a-z0-9\u0400-\u04FF]+('[a-z0-9\u0400-\u04FF]+)*/gi
    }
});
```

I'm no expert in Cyrillic so I've just added some Cyrillic characters to the character classes in the regular expression for illustration purposes. You could do better using [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) and its [Unicode plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/):

```
sel.expand("word", {
    wordOptions: {
        wordRegex: XRegExp("[\\p{L}\\d]+('[\\p{L}\\d]+)*", "gi")
    }
});
```